# Import a column from a database to matlab (missing fractional part of Time(3))

Tags: mysql, matlab

I have a table with a column of type `TIME(3)` and I to import it to MatLab. The problem is that the fractional part is not shown in the MatLab's Database Explorer even thought in the DB the fractional part is there.

At the right of the picture you can see the SQL Server Management Studio with all the data and information relative to the table, column types and a query. At the right side you have the MatLab Database Explorer connected to the same DB. If you look at the forth column (`canTime`) at each side of the picture you will see that on the right is missing the fractional part

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYF5R.png)

Comment: It is just a preview. I think you have fetch the value you will not lose any data.

Comment: I thought of that too but i actually lose the data. I tried to convert to datetime and the fractional part is not there =/